# Automated Outlook VB

Tags: vba, microsoft-outlook-2010

Have existing Outlook VB module that displays form where I can control how many emails are sent at once and how often they are sent out of DRAFT folder. Is it possible to run this module if O utlook is not open? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to run this module if Outlook is not open?

No, Outlook macros/vba run only when Outlook is running.